# why can I not just pass an int or bool directly into the OCMock's "andReturnValue" argument?

Tags: objective-c, ocunit, ocmock

I was trying to do:

```
[[[mockQuestion stub] andReturnValue:YES] shouldNegate];
[[[mockQuestion stub] andReturnValue:123] randomNumberWithLimit];
```

But that gave me this warning/error "incompatible integer pointer conversion sending 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to parameter of type 'NSValue *'"

The only way I could figure out to get around it was to do:

```
BOOL boolValue = YES;
int num = 123;

[[[mockQuestion stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(boolValue)] shouldNegate];
[[[mockQuestion stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(num)] randomNumberWithLimit];
```

But that makes my test code seem so overly verbose..  Is there a way to do this all inline without having to set variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a literal style that looks like `(type){value}`. This is commonly used to create struct literals but works for basic datatypes too. The important aspect here is that this type of literal creates a temporary that can be addressed. This means you can write your code like

```
[[[mockQuestion stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((BOOL){YES})] shouldNegate];
[[[mockQuestion stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((int){123})] randomNumberWithLimit];
```

Comment: Thanks, this should remove a fair amount of boilerplate in my tests!

Comment: Didn't know about this syntax either. Is it new? I'll update the OCMock documentation accordingly.

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg: They're called "Compound Literals" and they were introduced in C99. So they've been around for over a decade, although for some reason they haven't been very well-known.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is supposed to be an object pointer. In this case it should point to an object of the NSValue class.